# Can you include Fody in compilation generated with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn, fody

I have some code which I want to compile at runtime. I use Roslyn to compile the code. In that code I add a Fody MethodDecorator attributes because I want to capture the object instance passed to the method. However,
 the attribute doesn't get called when I run the code.
I run the code with `method.invoke`.
Does anyone have a suggestion?